# GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON - ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, backup

I'm setting up mysql replication using xtrabackup guide https://docs.percona.com/percona-xtrabackup/innovation-release/set-up-replication.html#2-copy-backed-up-data-to-the-replica

On Master/Source I'm running this command

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'root'@'12.34.56.78' IDENTIFIED BY 'asdfd34F4fg';
```

Gives error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'asdfd34F4fg'' at line 1
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What version of database server? Please run `SELECT VERSION();` and tell the result.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you do not want to change the `root` user's password so remove everything starting from `IDENTIFIED`.

Comment: The root and password is for replica server. I'm running this query on master/source server to grant permission to replica server.

Comment: If you are running mysql 8.0 then split the CREATE USER .. IDENTIFIED BY .. with the GRANT statement. The instruction to GRANT .. IDENTIFIED BY .. only works on old MySQL 5.x versions